# regex with {} not working

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to match more than 2 occurrences of `haha` in the following code. But `()` seems to be working as grouping. Why isn't it working?

```
>>> pattern="this is a joke hahahahahaaa. I cannot stop laughing hahahaaa"
>>> print(re.findall("(ha){2,}",pattern))
['ha', 'ha']
```

I wanted results to be:

```
['hahahaha', 'hahaha']
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: `((?:ha){2,})` will work. (Edited)

Comment: @GalAbra that won't catch the whole group.

Comment: it should be `['hahahahaha', 'hahaha']`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

s = '"this is a joke hahahahahaaa. I cannot stop laughing hahahaaa"'
result = re.findall(r'(?:ha){2,}', s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['hahahahaha', 'hahaha']
```

---

- `(?:ha){2,}` - matches the sequence `ha`(enclosed into group `(..)`) literally 2 or more times `{2,}` but considering it as non-capturing group
- `(?:...)` - match without capturing everything enclosed

Comment: what is ?: doing here in 
`
(r'((?:ha){2,})', s)
`

Comment: @Webair, added explanation

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest why does a non-capturing group help here?  (I know, but I think it'd be good to include in the answer)

Comment: I am confused on one thing... when I do
` 
pattern="this is a joke hahahahahaaa. I cannot stop laughing hahahaaa"
print(re.findall(r"((ha){2,})",pattern))

why it gives:

[('hahahahaha', 'ha'), ('hahaha', 'ha')]
` 
the 2nd elements 'ha' ? how that is coming

Comment: @Webair, because in the latter case you have 2 captured groups: one with the whole match `r'(....)'` and another one with sequence `(ha)`. Visually you observe one group nested in another, but they are all considered separately when generating the results of matching

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest still a bit confused... isn't the latter case

re.findall(r"((ha){2,})",pattern)


, supposed to match more than two occurences of 'ha' like 'haha','hahaha','hahahaha'